# Migrating October CMS to Wordpress

Tags: themes, migration, installation

I've done a lot of research on this and cant figure out what option is the best and quickest to take.

We currently have our website on October CMS and are looking to move it over to Wordpress.

Has anyone done this move before? I'm thinking of using a starter theme and then using a page builder to recreate all pages but that seems like a lot of coping and pasting of every section...

I'm wondering if anyone else has done a migration like this and has found another way of doing it while still being able to use a page builder to manage content?

Would really appreciate any tips, Thank you!